# iPhone SDK: How do I pass an array of values from a ViewController onto other ViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsmutablearray

I tried creating a method like below in `SecondViewController`:

```
-(void)setValue:(NSMutableArray*)array
 { 
      //NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      newArray = [array retain];
 }
```

and passing the value from `FirstViewController` using an object of `SecondViewController` named second:

```
[second setValue:existingArray];
```

`existingArray` is an NSMutableArray.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You don't mention what happens, but looking at your code, you don't need to do the alloc init for the newArray since the [array mutableCopy] would perform a shallow copy of array and put it inside newArray. You're leaking memory.

Comment: What happens is, it doesnot assign the value of `existingArray` to the `newArray`. Ok even I tried removing alloc init but den to it doesnot help. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you have set the array in the "`second`" object of a `SecondViewController`.

So you need to use that object for displaying the `SecondeViewController`, other wise how can it won't show the array.

Check the following code.

```
 //   In the FirstViewController

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender{

    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle: nil];
 [second setValue:existingArray];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
 [second release];

}
```

Here in the code I am assigning the data to the array in the "second" object and I am using that object to display the controller.

Regards,

Satya

Comment: @Satya: Thanks for the input. But When I move from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController` then there is an `IntermediateView`. `IntermediateView` is just a NSObject class not a UIViewController. The `FirstViewController` goes to the `IntermediateView` and then control goes to `SecondViewController`. So I suppose value of existingArray is not retained. I have set the @property and `@synthesize` for the `existingArray` but still does not help. What can be done in that case?

Comment: why do you need the IntermediateView? you will need to post more code if you want a useful answer..

Comment: @Parth: Do one thing, pass the array to the intermediate view. from the intermediate view pass the array to secondViewController. By that also you can do.

Comment: @SorinA: Actually this is an array, I am passing for creating coreplot. After getting the array values into the `newArray` the control goes to its header classes and then when it returns from the header classes the value is not retained. Also I have tried declaring a property and synthesizing the array but still it doesnt help in retaining the array values.

Comment: @Parth: once check, whether you are getting values from coreplot header. means check the existingArray consists values or not.

Comment: @Satya: Thanks for the input. Yeah first time when I print the array in console before going into header classes it shows 3 values in array but when I print the array after control returns, then it shows `(null)` value. What could be wrong?

Comment: @SorinA: which code you are asking for? The code where I fill in the `exitingArray`?

Comment: @Parth: Once check whether the array is released after passing the data to coreplot data Array. Try by passing the data using retain. like coreplotArray = [existingArray retain];  or else  [coreplotArray addObjectsFromArray:existingArray];

Comment: @Satya: Even I tried with `coreplotArray = [existingArray retain];` and `[coreplotArray addObjectsFromArray:existingArray];` but neither worked. What can be done?

Comment: @Parth: After Passing the existingArray to Coreplot Array, are you changing the existingArray; means are you assigning any data to existing Array? If yes, then the problem is there only, you are assigning null data to the existingArray.

Comment: @Satya: no I dont change the array. The `existingArray` array value changes only after the core plot is drawn. But here the value becomes null even before the coreplot can be drawn.

Comment: yes the code that you use to fill the array with data. also show us how you send data from one object to another.. edit the question and add more details.

Comment: @SorinA: basically values in my array comes from the webserver as I have my database on webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a property instead of the setter you have there(which looks bad). Question is do you really need to do a copy on the array or a retain would be enough?

Create a NSMutableArray *myArray as a local variable in the SecondViewController. Add a property @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray; in the interface.

Synthesize it and to set it just call [mySecondViewController setMyArray:newArray];

If you have instantiated correctly the SecondViewController and if the array that you want to send is not nil then it should work.

if you do it like this:

```
-(void)setValue:(NSMutableArray*)array
 { 
      NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      newArray = [array mutableCopy];
 }
```

newArray would be a variable declared inside the SetValue method, after the program exits the setValue method, the newArray variable will not be accessible anymore. Also you leak memory because newArray is never released.