# Copy Array elements into another class array

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4.2

I have an NSMutabaleArray with few contents, and want to copy the contents to another array in another class, the code:

sandboxcontroller.h:

```
@interface SandboxViewController : UIViewController
{

NSMutableArray * arrayOfDesc;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * arrayOfDesc;
```

SandboxContoller.m

```
@synthesize arrayOfDesc;

[arrayOfDesc addObject:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:location.coordinate.latitude longitude:location.coordinate.longitude]];
```

the class in with i want to copy:
NVMapViewController.h

```
@interface NVMapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
MKMapView *_mapView;
SandboxViewController * sandboxViewController;
NSMutableArray * points;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SandboxViewController *sandboxViewController;
```

NVMapViewController.m

```
points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sandboxViewController.arrayOfDesc] ;
```

When i log the points array, it gives me null. Where is there problem, can anyone suggest me, thanks.

And im not using ARC.

Comment: Is `sandboxViewController` actually set to something when you do the assignment to `points`?

Comment: yes, log `sandboxViewController` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you can get the solution:

[iPhone SDK: How do I pass an array of values from a ViewController onto other ViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076878/iphone-sdk-how-do-i-pass-an-array-of-values-from-a-viewcontroller-onto-other-vi)

There you can refer to **Satya**'s answer.

Let me know if you need more help

Hope this helps.