# (Beginner)Trying to pass an array from ViewController to DetailController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays

I have loaded an array (recordArray) in RootViewController class which I need to pass to the DetailViewController class so that I can access any variable within it.  I can pass a single value successfully, but I cannot get how to pass the whole array across.

I have created a second NSMutableArray recordArray in DetailsViewController.h, added the @property statement (with retain), and synthesized in DetailsViewController.m. I then added the following line in DetailsViewController.m

```
recordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.recordArray];
```

but that just gives me an empty array in the detail view.

I have read through some of the posts on this, but have not found anything which I understand sufficiently to be able to implement. I expect I'm going about this all wrong....

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: How is your detail view controller presented, storyboard or xib file?

Comment: Both ViewControllers are xib files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this code:

[iPhone SDK: How do I pass an array of values from a ViewController onto other ViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076878/iphone-sdk-how-do-i-pass-an-array-of-values-from-a-viewcontroller-onto-other-vi)

There you can refer to **Satya**'s answer.

Let me know if you need more help

**EDIT:**

Let us assume that there is an `NSArray` called `secondArray` declared in `SecondViewController`

Define a method in SecondViewController which says:

```
-(void)setValue:(NSArray *)array
{
    secondArray = array;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Parth and @Oscar. The posting by Satya was one that I have been trying to make sense of.  I have followed his suggestion, but on building I get a warning that it cannot find the setValue method.  I have added the setValue method to DetailViewController as Satya stated, and then set the array to the DetailViewController in the RootViewController code.

Comment: @user991542: Please refer to **EDIT** section of my answer.

Comment: Have you any idea why the call to setValue in the first ViewController cannot respond to the setValue method in the second ViewController?  Sorry it is just my inexperience in Objective-c letting me down here.

Comment: @user991542: No problems. I think you need to declare and define `-(void)setValue:(NSArray *)array` method in `SecondViewController` as I have mentioned in **EDIT** Section of my answer above, Please check my answer again.

Comment: I must be so close to solving this now!  setValue method is coded in second ViewController, but same warning message when I try to access it from first ViewController here `[DetailView setValue:recordArray];`  Thank you for your help Parth I will obviously accept this as the answer!

Comment: @user991542: Have you declared `-(void)setValue:(NSArray *)array` method in `SecondViewController.h`?

Comment: Ha - well I was defining the method in SecondViewController.m so that will hopefully explain that!  I will try getting it into .h without build errors!  Thanks again Parth.

Comment: @user991542: Yes declare it into `SecondViewController.h` and would pretty much do it. I am really glad that I could help you! :)

Comment: yes that is working now - thank you so much - I have been struggling with that for hours.  A good learning point for me.  Sorry I can't upvote you as I don't have enough reputation points yet!  Maybe I can come back to it when I do.

Comment: @user991542: Now you can have the reputation! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that here:

```
recordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.recordArray];
```

You are just assigning the same property `recordArray`, which is probably `nil` at this point, what you want to do is dependency injection. So whenever you instantiate your `DetailController`, you can do:

```
myDetailController.recordArray = myRecordArray
```

Where `myRecordArray` is the value you want to pass or "inject" in the detailview controller.