# share NSArray between different UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am making an application that uses a webService to get data in a JSON format... I get the data I parse them into a object NSArray ... and i use it .. it works fine ...
Now, if the user clicks a button I need to send him to an other Uiview ... which contains more data about the clicked object ..
The problem is here ... I don't want to request again and download the result from the server ... because i already did ... All I want is to have access to that NSArray that I have in the first UIViewController.

Comment: Refer to my answer in this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014353/beginnertrying-to-pass-an-array-from-viewcontroller-to-detailcontroller/10014473#10014473

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can add on AnotherView.h another property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *jsonData;
```

On AnotherView.m synthesize it. When you are going to to call AnotherView from InitialView, you can set jsonData with the data you retrieved on InitialView.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom initializer in your other view controller like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OtherViewController : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;

- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)anArray;

@end
```

Then implement it like so:

```
#import "OtherViewController.h"

@implementation OtherViewController
@synthesize myArray=_myArray;

- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)anArray {
    if (!(self = [self initWithNibName:@"OtherViewController" bundle:nil]))
        return nil;

    if (!anArray) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"OtherViewControllerBadInitCall" reason:@"array is nil" userInfo:nil];
    }

    _myArray = anArray;


    return self;
}

//...
@end
```

You can then init and display your controller like so:

```
OtherViewController *otherViewController = [[OtherViewController alloc] initWithArray:greatJSONArray];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:otherViewController animated:YES];
```

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the array as the property. You can either create a new class and set the array as the property and after you fetch the array, set the property. Or, you can create a property of the existing UIVIewController Class and pass the object.

Either way, you have to set property.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new property in your second ViewController that holds an NSArray and pass the firt array to the second ViewController before show it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have not outlined whether you send the data forward or backward. In the later case you will need to implement protocol and delegate(Define your own protocol) but for the prior case you just need to create the property of the Object you want to access in any other class. In case of web-services it is better to use protocol and delegates if u abide by the norms of MVC architecture.